# How to do something if an animation is stopped with .stop()?

Tags: jquery

**UPDATE:** I have made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xm57jdaUqthSYXc9p08D?p=preview) that represents my code in a very basic form. As you can see, you can navigate to "map2" and "map3" and then to "map4" and back to "map1" with ease as well as do multiple clicks on the "Go To" buttons without messing up the ability to navigate. However, if you "accidentally" click on the back button twice, suddenly the stacks get thrown off and it ruins the "navigating".

You can click on the "Go To" buttons as many times as you want and it will never mess up the navigation. How can I do the same for the back buttons?

The problem I know is that nothing is added to the "stack" variables when the "Go To" buttons are clicked unless the animations complete, but items are removed from the "stacks" soon as the "Back" button is clicked. I'm just not sure how to address this.

Below is my original code with original explanation of issue. However, if we can fix the Plunker representation, I will be able to understand how to fix this.

---

Below I have:

```
$scope.clickLinks = function(initialOut,initialIn,backIn,backOut,name){

    var $map = $('.'+initialOut+'Map');

    $map.stop().fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $('.'+initialOut+'Details,.bkbtn'+backOut).css("display","none");
        $('.'+initialIn+'Details,.bkbtn'+backIn).css("display","block");
        $('.noQuery').css("display","none");
        $("#buildingHeader").html(name);
        $('.'+initialIn+'Map').fadeIn('slow').css("display","block");

        stackMapOut.push(initialIn);
        stackMapIn.push(initialOut);
        stackBack.push(backIn);
        stackName.push(name);
    });
};
```

Works fine, everything stacks ok since nothing is pushed until the animation is complete. However, I have another set of elements that can be clicked that will basically backtrack the elements that are visible or not visible. Here is the code for that:

```
$scope.clickBack = function(){

    mapOut = stackMapOut.pop();
    mapIn = stackMapIn.pop();
    stackBack.pop();
    backIn = stackBack[stackBack.length-1];
    stackName.pop();
    nameShow = stackName[stackName.length-1];

    var $map = $('.'+mapOut+'Map');

    $map.stop().fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $('.'+ mapOut + 'Details,.bkbtn').css("display", "none");
        $('.' + mapIn + 'Details,.bkbtn'+backIn).css("display", "block");
        $(".noQuery").css("display","none");
        $("#buildingHeader").html(nameShow);
        $('.' + mapIn + 'Map').fadeIn('slow').css("display", "block");
    });
};
```

However, the "`stacks`" are being `pop`ped extra and I am not sure how to prevent that. I can't put them all inside the `.fadeOut` function this time because they need to be initiated when the click function runs.

The only thing I can think of personally is that I would need to find out how to "do something" if the animation is stopped. But I haven't a clue how to go about doing that or where to look.

Basically I need a way to prevent them from being `pop`ped if the animation stops. Or re`push` or something.

Comment: it's a bit hard to understand your issue without a demo that represents the problem

Comment: @charlietfl Added a Plunker representation.